# how to take integral of the Gamma Function

Tags: integration, gamma-function

Here is my question. I am trying to calculate the following integral:

$\int_{t}^{\infty} \Gamma(ax+b)dx$

I was not successful, although I tried many times.

I wonder if anyone can help me on this?

Thank you.

Comment: The integral diverges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An indefinite integral of
$$
\Gamma(s) := \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}\;dx,\quad \mathrm{Re}\;s > 0 ,
$$
is
$$
F(s) := \int_0^\infty \frac{(x^{s-1}-1)e^{-x}}{\log x}\;dx,\quad \mathrm{Re}\;s > 0.
$$
But $\lim_{s \to +\infty} F(s) = +\infty$, so $\int_t^{+\infty} \Gamma(ax+b)\;dx= +\infty$ if $a>1$.
Also $\lim_{s \to 0^+} F(s) = +\infty$, so $\int_t^{+\infty} \Gamma(ax+b)\;dx= +\infty$ if $0 < a < 1$.